# How to compare variables in JMeter for multiple/different variable sets

Tags: jmeter

I have several variables stored in my thread and I want compare between var1 vs var2 and var3 vs var4 and var5 vs var6 etc.

I have tried below code:

```
String var1 = vars.get("episodeTypeId");
String var2 = vars.get("aptidetid_2");

Failure = !var1.equals(var2);

if (Failure) {
  FailureMessage = "Variables are not equal. Expected \"" + var1 + "\" , actual:\"" + var2 + "\"";
}

String var3 = vars.get("duration");
String var4 = vars.get("aptduration_1");

Failure = !var3.equals(var4);

if (Failure) {
  FailureMessage = "Variables are not equal. Expected \"" + var3 + "\" , actual:\"" + var4 + "\"";
}
```

It's working only for two (Var1 vs var2), not remaining (eg, var3 vs var4 / var5 vs var6 etc.,). When I add more it's not validating.

Answer (score 0):

"not validating" doesn't tell a lot to us.

1. Check [jmeter.log file](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#logging) for any suspicious entries, it might be the case the variables don't exist.
2. Check variable values using [Debug Sampler and View Results Tree listener combination](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/debug-jmeter)
   3. Check your code for any syntax issues, I can only see you're comparing 2 variables and the code for remaining ones is missing. Also be aware that it's possible to compare 2 variables using "normal" [Response Assertion](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Response_Assertion):

   [image]

Comment: Thanks Dmitri for your response.. I'm repeating the above code for different variables, 

First two variables comparison:
String var1= vars.get("episodeTypeId");
String var2= vars.get("aptidetid_1");

Failure = !var1.equals(var2if (Failure) {
  FailureMessage = "Variables are not equal. Expected \"" + var1+ "\" , actual:\"" + var2 + "\"";
}

Second Set:
String var3= vars.get("duration");
String var4= vars.get("aptduration_1");

Failure = !var3.equals(var4);

if (Failure) {
  FailureMessage = "Variables are not equal. Expected \"" + var3+ "\" , actual:\"" + var4+ "\"";
}